# Proving a property of exponential function applied to linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, exponential-function

I'm having trouble proving a statement regarding the properties of the exponential function for linear bounded maps.More specifically, given a Banach space $X$ and a linear, bounded map $B:X \to X$ I want to show

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(I+\frac{1}{n} B)^n=e^B \tag{1} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}(I-\frac{1}{n} B^n)^{-n}=e^B
$$

where $e^B=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^k}{k!}$ and $I$ is the identity map. By the Binomial theorem I have

$$
(I+\frac{1}{n} B)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} B^k. 
$$

My idea was to show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} ||\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} B^n-e^B||=0. 
$$

Since $||B|| \in \mathbb{R}$ I think I have to  exploit the fact that (1) holds for real numbers. However, I do not see how to proceed.

Comment: If you can show that $(1+z/n)^n$ converges uniformly over compacts to $e^z$, then $(1+B/n)^n$ converges to $e^B$ by the continuity properties of the analytic functional calculus.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  %%
\Big\|\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}& \frac{1}{n^k} B^k-e^B\Big\|  = 
  %%
\Big\|\sum_{k=0}^{n} (1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)\cdot(1-\frac{k-1}{n}) 
  %%
 \frac{B^k}{k!} -e^B\Big\|\\ 
  %%
& \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \big|(1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)\cdot 
  %%
(1-\frac{k-1}{n})-1\big| \frac{\|B\|^k}{k!}+
  %%
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\|B\|^k}{k!}\rightarrow 0 
  %%
\text{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.
  %%
\end{align*}